# List Box databound problem

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

i bound the list box with data table.display member is "Code" and value member is "ID".no w i want to retrieve the all item of list box.but it return me system.data.datarow.how can i get all item from ListBox in this Case

Comment: Can you provide some more details or a code example?  Is this WinForms, ASP.NET or WPF?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn´t try to get the items from the ListBox, get them from the DataSource you have bound to the ListBox to in the first place.

Comment: Take it like a question 

Don't you think re-accessing the data source if we have the items in a list box is costly manipulating the listbox as an array is faster...

Comment: Why would going through the extra layer(s) of the listbox be faster?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DataRow` object to get the values of *Code* and *ID* columns:

```
foreach(var dr in ListBox1.Items)
{
    var code = dr["Code"];
    var id = dr["ID"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (object objObject in listBox1.Items)
            {
                System.Data.DataRowView objDataRowView = (DataRowView)objObject;
                if (!(objDataRowView["Column_Name"].ToString() == "Search String")
                {
                    Aray[i++]=objDataRowView["Column_Name"].ToString();
                }                    
            }
```

if Aray is a collection or Array of strings then it will have all the items of your search criteria in it or if you want to remove condition just remove if condition :D